# Running disqus_export on django-disqus app

Tags: django, disqus

I'm trying to export Django comments to the django-disqus app. When I run `python manage.py disqus_export --verbosity=0`, I get the following error lines:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/home/xx/webapps/xx/lib/python2.5/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/xx/webapps/xx/lib/python2.5/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/xx/webapps/xx/lib/python2.5/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/home/xx/webapps/xx/lib/python2.5/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/xx/lib/python2.5/django_disqus-0.4.1-py2.5.egg/disqus/management/commands/disqus_export.py", line 80, in handle
    forum_list = client.get_forum_list(user_api_key=settings.DISQUS_API_KEY)
  File "/home/xx/lib/python2.5/django_disqus-0.4.1-py2.5.egg/disqus/api.py", line 53, in call_method
    return self.call(attr, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xx/lib/python2.5/django_disqus-0.4.1-py2.5.egg/disqus/api.py", line 79, in call
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 124, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 387, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 498, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 425, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 360, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/urllib2.py", line 506, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: BAD REQUEST
```

See here: http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-disqus/en/latest/commands.html#disqus-export

The --dry-run command works, however, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Disqus may return a 400 if invalid credentials are provided. It's been a while since I've looked at django-disqus, but can you confirm that whatever credentials you've supplied are valid?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was wondering too, but the credentials are correct.